# SQL Database vs Object

Tags: sql, object, server-side

I realize this question has been asked in different forms but not quite in the same context as this so forgive me please.

I am developing a web based video game.  I have a library of over 5000 abilities, spells, skills, character classes, races, etc.

I want the client to receive information from the game library upon request from the server.

My first instinct was to create a library of all of the data in my SQL database, however since the data is static I am not sure if it would be best practice to create objects in my server-side code to store the information.

If anyone can provide some insight I'd appreciate it.

Thanks.

EDIT:  I'd like to add to most of the library items have roughly 256 characters of text (descriptions) along with the game related data.

Comment: 5000 is not such a big number, if they're static and don't take a lot of space, you can load them on startup and keep them in-memory. It will make your execution much faster and wouldn't require using a DB.

Comment: 5k rows or objects arent that much - but I would for ease of enhancement put those data in a database (embedded sqllite might work) and create your objects/instances via object-relation-managers (in Java e.g. something like JPA / Hibernate).

Answer (score 0):

5000 elements is a trivial amount of data for any modern DBMS to manage. If you are considering using a DBMS to manage this data, this would be advantageous over statically defining them in the server side code.

Separation of data from the "business logic" of running the game is very important. This allows you to add new definitions of items in the game, and customize the game without needing to modify any of your executable code to do so. This is also known as the [Model/View/Controller](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/model-view-controller-mvc-explained-through-ordering-drinks-at-the-bar-efcba6255053) design pattern.